# When queried from database instead of value [object HTMLInputElement] loaded in phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am new to **phonegap**. I used a select query to show the stored input value. Below is my database table.

```
function populateDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FuelDataEngine (price TEXT, ttl TEXT,odo TEXT,date TEXT)');

 price=document.getElementById('price');
 totallitres= document.getElementById('ttl');
 odometer=document.getElementById('odo');
 date=document.getElementById('date');

 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO FuelDataEngine (price,ttl,odo,date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [price,totallitres,odometer,date],successCB,errorCB);
```

I have to tabulate query Result.In tabulation query result showing [objectHTMLInput Element] coming.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
price=document.getElementById('price');
totallitres= document.getElementById('ttl');
odometer=document.getElementById('odo');
date=document.getElementById('date');
```

TO:

```
price=document.getElementById('price').value;
totallitres= document.getElementById('ttl').value;
odometer=document.getElementById('odo').value;
date=document.getElementById('date').value;
```

With out the `.value` you are actually saving the whole HTMLInput Element object instead of it's value

NOTE: `.value` is assuming all of the inputs are text fields, if this is not true you can look up how to get the value of other types of elements like textarea and select.